# Unable to update column with appropriate charset

Tags: php, mysql, non-ascii-characters

I'm experiencing a huge issue with the encoding and more exactly with the entries that go in my database. When I insert data, the characters are displayed properly. However, when I try to update the column, characters are misread into one of these: `Ð°Ð²Ð´Ð²Ð°Ð´Ð²Ð°`. In the same time, when I insert new rows, data looks like this in phpMyAdmin: `&#1050;&#1086;&#1085;`.

```
<form action="addItem.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label class='title' for="title"> Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="input"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label class='description' for="description"> Description</label>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="10" cols="35"></textarea>
    </p>    

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class='buttono' name="addEntry" id="addEntry" value="Add New Entry" />
    </p>
</form>
```

This is my **db.php**

```
<?php

class Db {

    public $mysql;

    function __construct() {
        $this->mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'to-do') or die("Unable to connect to database");
    }

    function delete_by_id($id) {
        $query = "DELETE from todo WHERE id = $id";
        $result = $this->mysql->query($query) or die("There was a problem");
    }

    function update_by_id($id, $description) {
        $query = "UPDATE todo
                 SET description = ?
                 WHERE id = ?";

         if ($stmt = $this->mysql->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('si', $description, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
         }
    }

}
```

This is my **addItem.php**

```
<?php

require 'db.php';
$db = new Db();

if (isset($_POST['addEntry'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO todo VALUES ('', ?, ?)";

    if ($stmt = $db->mysql->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['title'], $_POST['description']);
        $stmt->execute();
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

} else {
    die ($db->mysql->error);
}
```

What's wrong with it? I tried setting the charset to UTF-8 before the query gets executed but it's still the same (actually that seems not to be the issue).

Comment: Are the characters becoming HTML entities on both insert and update? or are insert and update behaving differently? Your description is unclear on that point.

Comment: They become HTML entities only when inserting. When I try to update they become `Ð°Ð²Ð´Ð²Ð°Ð´`

Answer (score 0):

You must set your mysql connection charset to UTF-8. You can use $mysql->set_charset("utf8") like this:

```
<?php

class Db {

    public $mysql;

    function __construct() {
      $this->mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'to-do') or die("Unable to connect to database");
      if (!$this->mysql->set_charset("utf8")) {
        throw new Exception("Error loading character set utf8: " .  $this->mysql->error);
      }

    }

    function delete_by_id($id) {
        $query = "DELETE from todo WHERE id = $id";
        $result = $this->mysql->query($query) or die("There was a problem");
    }

    function update_by_id($id, $description) {
        $query = "UPDATE todo
                 SET description = ?
                 WHERE id = ?";

         if ($stmt = $this->mysql->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('si', $description, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error loading character set utf8` + `Exception: Error loading character set utf8`

Comment: Still the same and for a reason. This code is not doing anything helpful in the scenario.